# How to compare a file and table data in JMeter?

Tags: sql-server, database, csv, jmeter, data-comparison

I have my source file as CSV format /Flat files.
My Target Table is SQL Server Database.

I need to compare both Source and Target and see the difference using JMeter.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Test Elements:

- [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) - to read the value(s) from CSV into JMeter Variable(s)
- [JDBC Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-retrieve-database-data-for-api-testing-with-jmeter) - to read the value(s) from the MS SQL Server database into JMeter Variable(s)
- [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) - to compare the variable(s) originating from the CSV file and from the database